# Can't assign type

Tags: java, android, class, assign

I hame class GameManager(),
int class variable:

```
public GameView view;
```

it's class constructor:

```
public GameManager (GameView view) 
   {
         this.view = view;
   }
```

in the class GameView I create :

```
private GameManager gameLoopThread;
....
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gameLoopThread = new GameView(this);// HERE IS ERROR ;
```

I dont know why it want to change gameLoopThread to GameView() type.

Answer (score 1):

`gameLoopThread = new GameManager(this);`